# ListView inside a fragment cannot be scrolled

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a following layout: [image]
Yellow background is list items, that stores in fragment.

Here is the code im mainActivity:

```
<fragment android:layout_width="140dp" 
          android:layout_height="100dp" 
          android:layout_below="@+id/block" 
          class="fragments.Demo"/>
```

Fragment Code:

```
public class Demo extends ListFragment{

 @Override
 public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    String[] values = new String[] { "Android", "iPhone", "WindowsMobile",
            "Blackberry", "WebOS", "Ubuntu", "Windows7", "Max OS X",
            "Linux", "OS/2" };

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this.getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.layout.list_item_bank, R.id.list_item_bank_name, values);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.transaction_list_fragment, null);
}
}
```

R.layout.list_item_bank:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:background="#ffee00"
         android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <TextView android:id="@+id/list_item_bank_name"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                 android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                 android:text=""
                 android:textColor="@color/abs__primary_text_holo_light"
                 android:textSize="18sp">
        </TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

The problem is: I can't scroll list view from main activity. What's wrong?

Comment: can you post your listView layout?

Answer (score 0):

whooops! seems to me I've found the problem. 
My ListFragment is inside a ScrollView. If I replace a scrollView with a LinearLayout everything works fine!